# How to write CSS for mobile cross-platform site

Tags: android, ios, css, mobile, pixel-ratio

iOS is easy, because the pixel-ratio is always either 1 or 2, and the target dpi is always pixels/ratio. Android, however uses 1.3, 1.5, and in some cases 2.25 for a pixel-ratio. I'm not aware of any way to set the target dpi to pixels/ratio for android devices, which would be an easy fix, but I imagine a pixel-imperfect solution for any display whose physical pixel count is an odd multiple of it's dips count (those 1.3's, 1.5's etc).

Right now I'm basically writing css for each `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`, and just multiplying my `px` values by that ratio manually (with slight adjustments for rounding). Using `em`s works great for fonts and a few other things, but I have to use `px`s for positioning and sizing of elements if I don't want half, empty, or overlapping pixels.

Is there a better way to do this?

If not, what is the best way to deal with background-images. I really don't want to have to re-write every single background-position for every icon for each ratio simply because I am changing the `background-size` for each `device-pixel-ratio`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [viewport](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html) meta tag. It lets you match width to the device's width. It also allows you to set initial scaling, set bounds on scaling, or even disable scaling. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892463/meta-viewport-questions) is a link to a relevant Stack Overflow question and answer on using the meta viewport tag.

Comment: I actually have the viewport all set up, but the device-width for android devices seems to be physical pixels, not dips. Do you know if that is correct? I guess my problem, really, is my obsession with pixel perfection. I can't stand the idea of having things scaled in some fashion.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have direct experience with that. I think scaling is just a part of modern web design, though. The best alternative that I can think of is using media queries to snap the website to different sized layouts based on the viewport, rather than doing it continuously.